# how do i print a "resultList" in a loop from java query and also print it out using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, sql

i get the result from a query using:

```
String query = "select a from TABLE a";
Query q = em.createQuery(query);
List<Type> res = q.setMaxResults(5).getResultList();
```

how do i print the list out using a loop? im trying this but i have to manually specify the value to print.

```
  Iterator<SplashPage> i = resultList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(i.next().adEndDate);
            System.out.println(i.next().adStartDate);
            System.out.println(i.next().compPAL);
            System.out.println(i.next().compSymbol);
            System.out.println(i.next().compUrl);
        }
```

^also from this some of values are not known?! it throws a NoSuchElementException as well

once i get the results i pass the list to a javascript function to prin out on a html page, but everything comes out "undefined" :(

Comment: Do you mean to go to the next row every time you print a value?

Comment: Every time you call ".next()" in the loop, you're moving to the next element in the list.

Comment: from this query i should get a list with 5 items in it right? and each item itself would have many fields right? so my expected output should be like "1. start end pal symbol" "2. start end pal symbol" etc right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `next` like that incrememts the iterator with each call. Since you have 5 `println` calls, each time through the loop you go over 5 different items.

You want

```
for (SplashPage page : resultList) {
   System.out.println(page.adEndDate);
   ...
}
```

You also can define a `toString` method on your entity class and use that, to cut down the number of prints....

Comment: is there a way to just print all out without typing "type.adEndDate"?

Comment: you could define a `toString` method on your entity and just print that.

Comment: i can do the same thing for the javascript? this sysout is for testing but i will  need to pass this resultList to a html page and use javascript to generate the result into a table. sorry if i am not using the correct terms.

Comment: java and javascript are not the same at all.  Ask a separate question for your javascript concerns